# libcublas.so.9.0 No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04

An error occurs when importing tensorflow.

My environment

- Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop
- Nvidia graphic driver 470.42.01
- CUDA 11.4
- Python 3.6.14 (Anaconda)
- TensorFlow-gpu 1.12.0

CUDA environment variable setup completed (11.4)
Linked symbolic link at /usr/local/CUDA from /usr/local/CUDA-11.4

(The reason for using the old version is that the SDK of the project was written in the past.)

When importing tensorflow after running Python, the following error occurs:

```sh
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/(username)/anaconda3/envs/mdk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/(username)/anaconda3/envs/mdk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/(username)/anaconda3/envs/mdk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/(username)/anaconda3/envs/mdk/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/(username)/anaconda3/envs/mdk/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/(username)/anaconda3/envs/mdk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/(username)/anaconda3/envs/mdk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/(username)/anaconda3/envs/mdk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/(username)/anaconda3/envs/mdk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/(username)/anaconda3/envs/mdk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/(username)/anaconda3/envs/mdk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/(username)/anaconda3/envs/mdk/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/(username)/anaconda3/envs/mdk/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I installed CUDA 9.0 to fix this error.
However, the same error came out with version 7.0.

Do I need to install all the versions of CUDA that I need?
Or is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: If you installed CUDA 9.0, you get a different error (most likely about cudnn), not the same error with version 7.0.

Answer (score 1):

According to Tensorflow documentation, TF v1.12 requires CUDA 9.0.
Take a look at screenshot for information, [image]

Once Appropriate CUDA version installed, Add the CUDA®, CUPTI, and cuDNN installation directories to the %PATH% environmental variable.
Follow the installation steps mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#ubuntu_1804_cuda_110) and change CUDA versions as per the requirement i.e CUDA 9.0.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when running `poetry lock` removed entries like the following from my lock file:

```
[[package]]
name = "nvidia-cublas-cu11"
```

My resolution was to run `poetry lock --no-update`.